# Please help tag these movie questions with a tag specific to work or franchise

Tags: discussion, tags

Each of the following questions are about a particular movie, but are tagged only with [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) or other generic tags.  This may be because the user who asked them didn't have enough reputation to create a tag.  (I suspect there are lots of questions like this, these are only some recent ones I quickly found.)

- [In "Close Encounters", what happened to the tall alien?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/57275/4918)
- [What is the connection between "Das Millionenspiel" and "The Running Man"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100894/4918)
- [How is the original Frankenstein movie (1931) different from the novel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6538/4918)
- [What was the intended meaning/interpretation of the movie Labyrinth (1986)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89455/4918)
- [In the book/movie Sphere, why was the space craft built with aerodynamics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5477/4918)
- [Could H.G. Wells "Time Machine" travel to an obstructed destination?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/23485/4918)
- [In Contact: Why not send a second pod?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2974/4918)

Can someone who knows more about movies please figure out if we already have a tag for that movie, or for the franchise or main work if the movie is part of a franchise, and retag?

Comment: I don't wanna be bothered, but can someone give @Mike an early Xmas present and request whether "[tag:magic]" tag can be deleted?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile: I think [tag:spells] is much worse than [tag:magic].

Comment: Isn't there something that deletes tag after a while if there is only one question tagged with it?

Comment: @DVK Sorry, gotta disagree on that one. [tag:magic] is one of those tags like [tag:spaceship] or [tag:vampire] which isn't franchise-specific but describes a **concept in SFF** which is interesting and worthy of general discussion. (I've written on the subject of these tags before on meta, but can't remember where.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: exactly, although many Harry Potter questions are tagged with [tag:magic] unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Done.

Comment: We need to have an individual tag for every damn work of SF ever written? And we have people busy creating these useless one-story tags, while another crew is busy destroying all the useful tags? Reminds me of a dystopian sci-fi story I read.

Comment: @user14111: Szathmári Sándor, *Kazohinia* shows a crew building new houses while another crew destroys the same houses after they are built, but that doesn't seem like a very good match.

Comment: @b_Jonas - I believe he's referring to ["The Good Work" by Theodore Thomas](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64346/utopia-where-no-one-has-to-work-but-people-want-to-work-anyway).

Comment: @amaranth - I was trying to centre it on both PC and mobile. It just won't line up though.